# Arduino Nano v3 atmega 328p avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino, atmega

i get this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

when trying to upload a example sketch.

pin (0,1) are not occupied;
it is the right serial port with latest drivers
i choosed the right board

The RX led blinks 2 or 3 times when i try to upload.

Full log:

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "D:\Utz\Downloads\arduino-1.0.4\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: 
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Are you programming an AVR from within the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting the RESET button just around the time `avrdude` starts. Maybe you were not entering the boot loader—the Nano is supposed to have auto-reset, but maybe that’s not working in your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as Igor mentioned, installing those FTDI drivers works.

> Install this driver after windows automatically installs usb driver. http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM20824_Setup.exe It worked for my arduino nano =D

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, The CDM 20.08.24 driver solved my Nano problem as well.

1. Uninstall previous com port ftdi driver via "Device Manager", select
   delete software option
2. Install the recommended 20824 driver
3. Restart as Windows recommends.
4. Nano 3.0 is now programmable!

Answer (score 0):

**Prevent Arduino from resetting**

Make sure there is:

- a 120 ohm resistor between Vcc (+5V) and the Arduino's \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ pin

OR

- a 10μF capacitor from \$\overline{\text{RESET}}\$ to GND.

When the programming cycle starts, Arduino will reset when one of the above hacks is not in place. The PC software will timeout before Arduino is back online.

**Baudrate**

Find this line in your ArduinoISP sketch, the software you use to turn Arduino into an AVR programmer:

```
Serial.begin(19200);
```

and change it to:

```
Serial.begin(57600);
```

Upload, retry.

Comment: While I can't entirely rule it out, this doesn't really sound like an ISP situation to me; rather I suspect just a usb-serial cable used with the bootloader on the target chip.

Answer (score 0):

Install this driver after windows automatically installs usb driver.
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/CDM/CDM20824_Setup.exe
It worked for my arduino nano =D